# How to use multiple $group in sub array object mongodb aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm using mongodb for nodejs server. I have faced a problem when using aggregate. Below is my design document

```
{  
    "app_id" : "a6e3a",    
    "ref" : "google.com",
    "samples" : [ 
        {          
            "num_visitor" : 2,
            "spend" : 285,                      
        }, 
        {           
            "num_visitor" : 3,
            "spend" : 236,                       
        }
    ],
    "location" : [ 
        {
            "country_code" : "DE",
            "vis" : 1,         
        }, 
        {
            "country_code" : "DE",
            "vis" : 1,          
        }, 
        {
            "country_code" : "US",
            "vis" : 2,            
        },
        {
            "country_code" : "US",
            "vis" : 1,            
        }
    ],
    "device" : [ 
        {
            "type" : " isFireFox 64",
            "tran" : 1,            
        }, 
        {
            "type" : " isFireFox 64",
            "tran" : 1,            
        },         
        {
            "device" : " isChrome isWebKit 71",
            "tran" : 3,           
        }
    ]   
}
```

i have searched all in Stack Overflow, try using mapReduce but can not have expected result, i want group by app_id and in sub array location or device group by field and sum value.  here my pipeline and stuck here

```
 [ {
            $match: {
                ref: "google.com"                
            }
        },

        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                location: 1,
                device: 1
            }
        },

        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$location.country_code",
                tags: { $sum: "$location.views" }
            }
        }
]
```

my actual expected output is

```
[
    {
        _id:"a6e3a",
        total_visitor:5,
        location:[
            {
                country_code:"DE",
                vis:2
            },
            {
                country_code:"US",
                vis:3
            }
        ],
        device:[
            {
                type:"isFireFox 64",
                tran:2
            },
            {
                type:"isChrome isWebKit 71",
                tran:2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

please help me or suggest me what Aggregation Pipeline Stages must use in this case